# Is this one of the use case to use React.useMemo?

Tags: reactjs, react-usememo

Does returning a JSX like below considered as a expensive computation/calculation ? I read a few articles including Kent C Dodds article about when to use useMemo and useCallback. Most of them explicitly say to use those API when your apps feel slow. Would love to know what the React community think about this

Here is my code:

```
...few codes above
const dynamicJSX = React.useMemo(() => {
        switch(input.vitalType) {
            case 'BLOOD_PRESSURE': {
                return (
                    <Col span={24}>
                        <Row gutter={16}>
                            <Col lg={12} md={24} sm={24} xs={24}>
                                <Input
                                    type="text"
                                    name="systolic"
                                    label={t('label.systolic')}
                                    onChange={onChange}
                                    value={input.systolic}
                                    error={error.systolic}
                                    required={true}
                                    onPressEnter={onPressEnter}
                                />
                            </Col>

                            <Col lg={12} md={24} sm={24} xs={24}>
                                <Input
                                    type="text"
                                    name="diastolic"
                                    label={t('label.diastolic')}
                                    onChange={onChange}
                                    value={input.diastolic}
                                    error={error.diastolic}
                                    required={true}
                                    onPressEnter={onPressEnter}
                                />
                            </Col>
                        </Row>
                    </Col> 
                )
            } 

            case 'GLUCOSE': {
                return (
                    <Col span={24}>
                        <Row gutter={16}>
                            <Col lg={12} md={24} sm={24} xs={24}>
                                <Select
                                    label={t('label.conditions')}
                                    name="conditions"
                                    required={true}
                                    onChange={(value) => onSelectChange('conditions', value)}
                                    value={input.conditions}
                                    error={error.conditions}
                                    placeholder={t('opt.select_one')}
                                    dropOptions={[
                                        { label: t('opt.fasting'), value: 'FASTING' },
                                        { label: t('opt.after_meal'), value: 'AFTER_MEAL' },
                                        { label: t('opt.hours_after_meal'), value: '2_TO_3_HOURS_AFTER_MEAL' }
                                    ]}
                                />
                            </Col>
                                    
                            <Col lg={12} md={24} sm={24} xs={24}>
                                <Input
                                    type="text"
                                    name="value"
                                    label={t('label.value')}
                                    onChange={onChange}
                                    value={input.value}
                                    error={error.value}
                                    required={true}
                                    onPressEnter={onPressEnter}
                                />
                            </Col>
                        </Row>
                    </Col>
                )
            }

            default:
                return (
                    <Col lg={12} md={24} sm={24} xs={24}>
                        <Input
                            type="text"
                            name="value"
                            label={t('label.value')}
                            value={input.value}
                            error={error.value}
                            required={true}
                            onPressEnter={onPressEnter}
                            onChange={onChange}
                        />
                    </Col>
                )
        }
    }, [input.vitalType]);
    
return (
   <div>
      /// few codes here
     {dynamicJSX}
   </div>
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you need to specify dependencies in your `useMemo` for the props you are using like `onChange`, `onPressEnter` and so on. Now it won't make much performance difference in this case as component is going to re-render anyways prop changes and so is `useMemo`.

Main use case of `useMemo` is in side effects, when we do some calculation like as result of async task its better to memoize the result instead of recomputing on every render.

Comment: ahh i see. im curious actually. what happen if i use useMemo and useCallback without passing dependencies, will it be recreated every time also ?

Comment: If you pass no second arg as dependency array then it will run on every render. If you pass empty [] then it will run only on first render bt it you pass list of array then it will only run when reference dependencies change.